# WARNING hook before_worker_boot failed with exception (URI::InvalidURIError) bad URI(is not URI?): "DATABASE_URL=\"postgres://resume_builder\""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

i am trying to rails server someone's project for learning purpose. But this error comes up when setting up with postgresql please help.

```
rails aborted!
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): "DATABASE_URL=\"postgres://resume_builder\""
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:73:in `parse'
```

this is the stack trace
below is the database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: resume_builder
  url: "postgres://localhost/somedatabase"
  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  username: resume_builder

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  password: test

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  # <<: *default

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
  DATABASE_URL="postgres://resume_builder"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  url: postgres://resume_builder
```

7055] WARNING hook before_worker_boot failed with exception (URI::InvalidURIError) bad URI(is not URI?): "DATABASE_URL="postgres://resume_builder""
[7052] WARNING hook before_worker_boot failed with exception (URI::InvalidURIError) bad URI(is not URI?): "DATABASE_URL="postgres://resume_builder""
error that comes up on rails server

Comment: Please share the whole error message and the stack trace. And share how you set up postgresql.

Comment: edit my question for you

Answer (score 1):

YAML file cannot have **=**, as it is **not** in the specification of YAML.

Connecting Database with url has standard way.

URL is divided in following information
**adapter, username, password, domain, database name**

For example,

```
            postgresql://ecldev@localhost/post_development
```

here,

1. postgres = adapter
2. ecldev = username
3. localhost = domain
4. post_development = database name

note - **@** is mandatory.

In your case url is "postgres://resume_builder". Is does not have username, domain.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL8YF.png)

### UPDATE

just change

`DATABASE_URL="postgres://resume_builder"` to `DATABASE_URL: "postgres://resume_builder"`

Comment: production:
  <<: *default
  url: postgresql://db@localhost/resume_builder
 added this but then could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?  THIS error came up

Comment: Where have you hosted your db for production?? if you hosted your application on heroku, then heroku provides database url